# How to force serial/sequential execution of AsyncTasks in Android 2.x

Tags: android, android-asynctask

There are a few Android APIs (after donut and before honeycomb) if Im not mistaken, where Google have enabled the AsyncTasks to run paralelly aiming for faster execution. Then lots of devs made mistakes when reaching out to the same database using multiple AsyncTasks, and since Android 3.0 AsyncTasks are running serially by default.

I am suffering this problem now when testing my app on an Android 2.3.4 device with my SQLite

- First, Im getting categories from the server, I open DB, insert them close DB.
- Second I get the subcategories from the server, open DB, insert them into DB, close DB
- Third I get user items from the server, open DB, insert items, then close DB

Im taking good care to ensure that one starts after another, but in every 8-10 iterations something somewhere slows down and overlaps with another procedure right in the moment where a task is opening the db, another task closes it right after, and the first task starts trying to write to a closed db....

What do I do? I want clean, reliable separation, sequential execution and I dont want to start the asynctasks from the previous asynctask's onPostExecute, because these three will not always run in a row

I read an article yesterday that you CANT do it on android 2.x

Shall I try to open the DB and DBHelper before ALL of the operations and close the DB afterwards?

EDIT: Usually I get the error here (at Begin transaction):
(The error says that the DB is closed)

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    // dbTools.close();

    try {
        if (database == null) {
            database = dbTools.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    database.beginTransaction();

    try {

        // Iterating all UserItem objects from the LinkedHashSet and getting their info
        for (UserItem userItem : userItems) {


            // Inserting values for the database to insert in a new record
            values.put(C.DBColumns.ITEM_ID, userItem.getItemId());
            values.put(C.DBColumns.ITEM_NAME, userItem.getItemName());


            // database.insertWithOnConflict(C.DBTables.ITEMS, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            database.insert(C.DBTables.ITEMS, null, values);

        } // End of For loop

        database.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } finally {

        database.endTransaction();

    }

    // Closing all cursors, databases and database helpers properly because not closing them can spring lots of trouble.
    if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
        try {
            database.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;

} // End of doInBackground
```

And this is my DBTOOLS CLASS:

```
public class DBTools extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Its a good practice for DBTools to be a singleton. Do not instantiate it with "new DBTools(context)" but with
    // DBTools.getInstance(context) instead
    private static DBTools sInstance;

    public static DBTools getInstance(Context context) {

        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DBTools(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public DBTools(Context context) {
        super(context, C.Preferences.LOCAL_SQLITE_DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableCategoriesCreate);
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableSubcategoriesCreate);
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableItemsCreate);
    }

    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableCategoriesCreate);
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableSubcategoriesCreate);
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableItemsCreate);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableCategoriesDrop);
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableSubcategoriesDrop);
        database.execSQL(SQLQueries.tableItemsDrop);
        onCreate(database);
    }

} // End of Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't call from onPostExecute, I would say you have two options, one would be to move your open close calls to the beginning and end of your activity or service.

Option two would be to setup a reference counter in your DB and DBHelper where you track the number of times open has been called, and then decrement that count when close is called. That way you can perform close only when the count is 0. One thing to remember when taking this approach is that you should probably have a method that will force the db to close that you call when you are sure your other connections are done. This shouldn't be necessary but will be a failsafe to ensure the db gets closed if something goes wrong.

Edit: You would have to make DBTools a singleton for it to work, but it's not equivalent. Here's a quick example.

```
public class DBTools {
   private static DBTools instance;
   private static int openCount;

   public DBTools getInstance() {
     if (instance == null) {
       instance = new DBTools();
     }
     return instance;
   }

   private DBTools() {
     openCount = 0;
   }

   public void open() {
     openCount++;
     //Do open 
   }

   public close() {
     openCount--;
     if (openCount == 0) {
        //Do close
     }

   public void forceDBClose() {
      //Do close 
   }
}
```

Comment: is option b equivallent to making DBtools a singleton ?

Comment: You need to use a singleton but it's not a matter of just making it a singleton I've added some code for reference.

Comment: so forceDBClose is called when openCount > 1?

Comment: So forceDBClose would be called when you want to close the database and don't care how many connections are open. For example if the user is existing the app for instance. You don't won't be reading the database anymore, so you can just close it.

It's worth noting if the rest of your code is solid, you probably won't need that method, it more of a safety net to ensure the database is being closed.

Comment: helped me solve my issue, so Im accepting this answer. Still dont know how to force asynctasks to run in sequence, though

Answer (score 1):

I am also a newbee in android. I was having a problem like this too.
To overcome this, i used **Singleton class**.

I created one instance of the DBHelper class and used it in all my asynctasks.
So, until the DB is closed, all the asynctasks access the initialised DB object.
If there is no object in the memory, the async tasks, instantiates it and use it then.

Comment: I've already done that but didnt help :( I will attach some code to my question